# Scroll of previous view in iphone App doesnt get disabled in the next view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, addsubview

i have two views say A & B. Both are the subclass of UIViewController class..View A is not a Table View but it is a scroll enabled view as it is more than the iphone dimensions 320*460. View B is not a scroll View. I am calling view B while clicking some button in View A like,

```
-(IBAction)bt:id(Sender)
    {
        B *mB=[[B alloc]initWithNib:@"B" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubView:mB.view];
    }
```

the problem is, As View A is larger, therefore when B is loaded over View A, even View A is partially visible in View B.please help me in overcome this problem??

Comment: have you added UIScrollView in the View A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions but I have founda different solution to my problem.

When adding another view i.e. View B over Scroll View A, I reset the scroll view dimensions of A accordingly so that it is not visible. Also, when I press the Back button in View B, I again set the scroll View dimensions of View A to its previous value. Also, I made View A the delegate of View B since on pressing Back Button in B, I need to call a function which is defined in View A and is a part of View B protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Before Adding  view B to Main view remove the view A from its superview.

in .h take two objects

ViewA *aObject;
ViewB *bObject;

In View DidLoad  create tow objects of View A and View B like this way

aObject=[[ViewA alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewA" bundle:nil];

bObject=[[ViewB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewB" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubView:aObject.view];

When You want to add View B add this code

[aObject.view removeFromSuperView];

[self.view addSubView:bObject.view];

Similarly IN Back Button action you can add code like

[bObject.view removeFromSuperView];

[self.view addSubView:aObject.view];

Try this code of snippets in your application I hope it will helps you. It wont lost your previous values of calss

Comment: No but i want to preserve View A as well as i need to come back to A by clicking Back button in View B.

Comment: in Back button action when you come back then you need to remove view band add again view A and

Comment: but if i do so, the values which are their in different fields in view A will be removed.I dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are adding view B to View A Subview and View A is in the scroll View so you need create a separate UIView Outlet and UIView in Interface Builder smallViewB the View A whatever size you need to display View B.

Then Add subview to View Outlet you created Above .
Please let me know if the problem persisting.

```
@interface ViewController A:UIViewController
@property(nonautomic,retain)IBOutlet UIView *smallViewB;

@implementation ViewController A
@synthesize smallViewB; //Make connection smallViewB in Interface Builder.

-(IBAction)bt:id(Sender) 
{ 
   B *mB=[[B alloc]initWithNib:@"B" bundle:nil];
   [self.smallViewB addSubView:mB.view];
}
```

Comment: @Pandey..i will do that and will respond by evening..plz share if u find something else as well..thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in you **-(IBAction)bt:(id)Sender**

```
ViewA.your_scroll_view.scrollEnabled=NO;
```

This might be what you wanted to do, if i understood it right.